# Update panel with a .net Calendar control having issues with asynctriggers & VisibleMonthChanged event

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I've got the following update panel wrapping around a Calendar control in .net

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="CalendarPanel" UpdateMode="conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Calendar ID="ClubCalendar" runat="server" Width="800" height="500"  DayHeaderStyle-CssClass="dateDayItem"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ClubCalendar" EventName="SelectionChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ClubCalendar" EventName="VisibleMonthChanged" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My issue is with the `VisibleMonthChanged` event

I get the following error when loading the page

```
 The 'VisibleMonthChanged' event on associated control 'ClubCalendar' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'CalendarPanel' does not match the standard event handler signature.
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

While I still don't know if its possible to setup the trigger for the `VisibleMonthChanged` event I was able to work around this by setting up the event in the code behind

```
 ClubCalendar.VisibleMonthChanged +=new MonthChangedEventHandler(ClubCalendar_VisibleMonthChanged);
```

and then calling the Panel update method manually.

```
void ClubCalendar_VisibleMonthChanged(Object sender, MonthChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartDate = e.NewDate;
        CalendarPanel.Update();
    }
```